# Does cat urine really fluoresce? If so, why?

Tags: biochemistry

I temporarily got caught in the Sad and Useless website, and found [Science is Fun](https://www.sadanduseless.com/science-is-fun/).

Most of the claims seem plausible, but I can't guess why cat urine would fluoresce.

Comments have directed me to [Why Does Urine Glow Under a Black Light?](https://www.thoughtco.com/why-urine-glows-under-black-light-609449) which says:

> You can use a black light to detect body fluids. It's actually a good way to look for pet urine or make sure a bathroom or hotel room is really clean. Cat urine, in particular, glows very brightly under ultraviolet light. **Urine glows under a black light primarily because it contains the element phosphorus. Phosphorus glows yellowish green in the presence of oxygen, with or without black light**, but the light imparts additional energy that make the chemiluminescence easier to see. **Urine also contains broken down blood proteins that glow under a black light.**

Certainly other mammals including humans have both phosphorus and broken down blood proteins in their urine, so is the proposed specificity to cat urine just an issue of concentration perhaps?

[image: www.sadanduseless.com/science-is-fun/ cat pee glows under black light]

Comment: I don't find it implausible, but why cat urine specifically, and not of other animals?

Comment: I actually think thoughtco simplifies quite a bit. I don't think there is pure P in urine.

Comment: Could possibly be because of Urobilin. Also, diet also influences the urine composition. Some of the excreted products can be fluorescent (for e.g. riboflavin)

Comment: Cat is a carnivore. Myoglobin is also a heme protein and its breakdown would also produce the "bile pigments" and their downstream excretion metabolites. It is possible that a carnivore might produce more bile pigments because of their diet, compared to a herbivore. However, I am not sure about it.

Comment: @John Dvorak: In fact, other sorts of urine, including human, fluoresce under UV light.  Don't happen to have a cat, so I can't check relative intensity :-)